# What function does the "workplace-rhythm" tag serve

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [workplace-rhythm](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workplace-rhythm) seems to have no discernable meaning as it has no description.

Should we just get rid of it?

Comment: If it has no description then we should focus on giving it one :) I see 42 questions currently, and the tag dates back to 2012... so yes, editing its wiki seems recommended.

Comment: In actual usage, its implementation seems rather random and of little to no value. At least I'm not seeing any common understanding of intent among the 42 questions. I'd get rid of it. IMHO, fewer is better.

Comment: I don't see any reason to keep it.

Comment: +1 on deletion, adding tag.

Comment: Digging into the uses of the tag, I see that some posts will be left without any tag, and some with only one tag if we reach consensus to remove it. I noticed that most of the single case uses were made by a single user. In any cases we would have to replace for a proper replacement (browsing I saw about 4,5 that only have that tag)... I'm now more inclined and agree with the other comments above (go for deletion), although we still have to consider a replacement tag for some of those posts, case by case...

Answer (score 4):

Some clusters of questions cover:

- Work interruptions/distractions and maintaining focus (productivity)
- Finding work meaningful, not being bored (work/life balance)
- Social interactions with colleagues (professionalism, company-culture)
- Personal conflicts with colleagues, managing stressful work situations (conflict)

In my opinion, this is too many different interpretations of what it means for the tag to be applied consistently, and we should either get rid of it or write a description of the sorts of questions it should be applied to.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting rid of the tag we should address each of the questions to make sure the tags they are left with make sense. This may require that each question be re-tagged.

If this is done correctly then the tag will have no questions remaining, or a core group of questions that will make it easy to write a tag wiki.

Comment: How do we know whether a question is tagged properly if we don't know the intended meaning of the tag? Shouldn't we write the tag wiki first? Or are you assuming that there is some question in that list that has a topic that isn't already covered by the existing 540 or so tags?

Comment: This step takes time and effort.

Comment: That doesn't help me understand how we are supposed to know whether the tag belongs on a question or not. I don't think we can know that if we don't agree on what it should be used for.